# Possibilities of submit a form on (left-/middle-/open-in-new-tab-or-window-)clicking an html link

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Using jQuery, I would like to submit a POST form on clicking an html link, **into the target browser tab where the link is opened**.

This is

```
<a id="submit_button" href=".">Search for values</a>
<script>
    $('#submit_button').click(function() {
        $('#my_form').submit();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

submits the form as desired if the link is clicked with the mouse.
But

- if the middle button is clicked to open the link in a new tab, I would like to see the form being submitted in that new tab
- if the right button is clicked and "open link in new tab" or "open link in new window" is chosen from the menu, I would like to see the form being submitted in the chosen way

Any ideas or pointers how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you really want it to be link?

Comment: The "open link in new tab" behavior is problematic. The first on is simple.

Comment: @ChristianStump, misread, will update.

Comment: @dfsq not necessarily. I want something that looks like a link, has the "open in new tab" possibilities of a link, and which submits the form.

Comment: If form method is GET then it's pretty simple. Otherwise it's also possible but not that easy.

Comment: The original and the new window/tab know nothing of each other by default in this scenario. You could try and get them to communicate via `postMessage` … and then have the new tab set a (random) `window.name` for itself, have it communicate that name back to the opening tab (caveat: _which one_, if there are several tabs of the originating site open already?), and have it set that dynamically as form `target` …

Comment: Would be simpler if you’d offered that to the user as a possibility to chose besides their normal browser mechanism – let’s say a checkbox labeled “open result in a new tab”, and then have your submit handler check that before submitting, and set `target="_blank"` on the form if checkbox is checked.

Comment: The question: what submit method are you interested in GET/POST?

Comment: @dfsq: already updated the question, it's a POST form...

Comment: the content is too large to put it into a GET form (which afaik is limited to <2000 characters).

Comment: Too bad, with GET it's quite easy to achieve all you need. With POST it's tricky.

Comment: @dfsq, I agree, one could change the href with `get`

Comment: if that's too hard, it might be the best to actually use a submit button (css'ed to look like a link), only allowing submit button actions, plus adding a middle mouse click action.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#submit_button').click(function(e) {        
    $(this).attr("href", "javascript:void(0)"); //reset by every click.
    $('#my_form').removeAttr("target"); //reset        
    if (e.button == 1) //middle mouse button
    {
        e.preventDefault(); //stop the default behavior of the middle mouse button
        $('#my_form').attr("target", "new_window");
    }
    $('#my_form').submit();




    return false;
});
```

You could try this code for the middle mouse button, for the open in new tab variant you could do this. It's really dirty, so dirty it becomes good!

```
$('#submit_button').contextmenu(function(e) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      //You do want to check here if the unload came from the right source

      localStorage.setItem(name, $('#your_inputs').val());
      //save your form data to local storage

    }
    $(this).attr("href", location.href);
    //set the link to reload itself
    $('#my_form').attr("target", "new_window");
    //set the target to a new window
});

//put this by default on your page, when it detect local storage submit.
window.onload = function() {

    var name = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if (name !== null)
    {
      //repopulate the form and send to server using normal post
      //delete the local storage items after this.
    }
}
```

Comment: That does handle the middle click, so certainly a step forward, thanks. But using the menu's "open in new tab" is not covered, though it seems to be too hard according to other comments above.

Comment: @ChristianStump, I've came up with a solution. I don't think it's the worth the effort, just accepting that the `open in new window` post won't be available for your users will be easier I think.